# How do I create a new fragment that opens a full screen video view from the previous fragment when maximized?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on an app where I am supposed to open a video view in landscape mode ,when the video is clicked in portrait mode. I plan to add a fragment to do that, but i want to preserve the states of everything in the previous view so the call is not interrupted. is there a way to do this?
Here's my fragment code:

```
public class SecureRoomCallFragment extends BaseCallFragment {
@BindView(R.id.callStatusContainer)
ViewGroup callStatusContainer;
@BindView(R.id.callNameText)
TextView callNameText;
@BindView(R.id.callParticipantCountText)
TextView callParticipantCountText;
@BindView(R.id.callDurationText)
TextView callDurationText;
@BindView(R.id.activeSpeakerContainer)
ViewGroup activeSpeakerContainer;
@BindView(R.id.activeSpeakerVideo)
ViewGroup activeSpeakerVideo;
@BindView(R.id.activeSpeakerImage)
ImageView activeSpeakerImage;
@BindView(R.id.activeSpeakerName)
TextView activeSpeakerName;
@BindView(R.id.callProgressContainer)
ViewGroup callProgressContainer;
@BindView(R.id.callProgressName)
TextView callProgressName;
@BindView(R.id.callProgressText)
TextView callProgressText;
@BindView(R.id.groupCallerList)
RecyclerView groupCallerList;
@BindView(R.id.callButtonContainerUnavailable)
ViewGroup callButtonContainerUnavailable;
@BindView(R.id.callButtonCancel)
Button cancelButton;
@BindView(R.id.callButtonRetry)
Button retryButton;
@BindView(R.id.full_screen_image)
ImageView fullScreenImage;

private GroupCallAdapter callerAdapter;
private int totalNumberOfUsers = -1;
private static final int MAX_NUM_USERS_ALLOW_IN_CALL = 10;
private boolean isFullScreen = true;
private boolean isScreenShareEnabled = false;
private String screenshareuserID;
private String participantuserID;
public SecureRoomCallFragment(final int totalNumberOfUsers) {
this.totalNumberOfUsers = (totalNumberOfUsers < MAX_NUM_USERS_ALLOW_IN_CALL) ? totalNumberOfUsers : MAX_NUM_USERS_ALLOW_IN_CALL;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call_room, container, false);
ButterKnife.bind(this, layout);


resetUI();
callProgressName.setText(callHelper.getConvo().getName());
callNameText.setText(callHelper.getConvo().getName());
return layout;
}


@Override
protected void onCallConnected() {
if (!callHelper.getConvo().isPrivateChat()) {
callProgressText.setText(getString(R.string.call_status_connected));
callProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
groupCallerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
callStatusContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
}

@Override
protected void onCallCompleted() {
DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
callProgressText.setText(getString(R.string.call_status_completed));
callProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
groupCallerList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
getActivity().finish();
}
};
showAlert(getString(R.string.dialog_title_meeting_end), getString(R.string.dialog_message_meeting_end), getString(android.R.string.ok), positiveClickListener, true /* isModal */);
}

@Override
protected void onUserJoined(@NonNull Participant participant, final int participantSize) {
if (participant == null) {


return;
}


participantuserID = participant.userId;

if (callProgressContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
callProgressText.setText(getString(R.string.call_status_connected));
callProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
groupCallerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
callStatusContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

final boolean isActiveParticipant = callHelper.isActiveParticipant(participant);

if (isActiveParticipant) {
final Caller activeCaller = callHelper.getActiveCaller();
if (activeCaller != null) {
final Participant activeParticipant = activeCaller.getParticipant();

activeSpeakerVideo.removeAllViews();
activeSpeakerVideo.addView(activeParticipant.videoPlayer.videoView, videoLayoutParams);

activeSpeakerName.setText(activeCaller.getName());


activeSpeakerName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
if (activeCaller.getImage() != null) {
activeSpeakerImage.setImageBitmap(activeCaller.getImage());
} else {
activeSpeakerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.call_default_profile);
}
activeSpeakerImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
activeSpeakerImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

showActiveSpeakerVideo(!activeCaller.isVideoPaused());
showControlButtons(true);
}
}

callerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
callParticipantCountText.setText("( " +participantSize+" / "+totalNumberOfUsers+" )");

super.onUserJoined(participant, participantSize);
}

@Override
protected void onUserLeft(@NonNull Participant participant, final int participantSize) {
if (participant == null) {
return;
}



final boolean isActiveParticipant = callHelper.isActiveParticipant(participant);


if (isActiveParticipant) {
final Caller activeCaller = callHelper.getActiveCaller();
if (activeCaller != null) {
swapVideoView(activeCaller);
} else {
showActiveSpeakerVideo(false);
activeSpeakerName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
} else {
callerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
callParticipantCountText.setText("( " +participantSize+" / "+totalNumberOfUsers+" )");
}

@Override
protected void onUserVideoPaused(@NonNull Participant participant, boolean isVideoPaused) {
if (participant == null) {
return;
}

final boolean isActiveParticipant = callHelper.isActiveParticipant(participant);

if (isActiveParticipant) {
showActiveSpeakerVideo(!isVideoPaused);
} else {
callerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}

@Override
protected void onDurationTick(long duration, @NonNull String formattedString) {

callDurationText.setText(formattedString);
}

@Override
protected void onAVDEvent(@NonNull String avdUserID) {
final Caller activeCaller = callHelper.getActiveCaller();

if (activeCaller != null) {
swapVideoView(activeCaller);

}
}

@Override
protected void onScreenShare(boolean inScreenShare, @NonNull String userID, @NonNull int width, @NonNull int height) {
isScreenShareEnabled = inScreenShare;
screenshareuserID = userID;

if (inScreenShare) {
fullscreenvideodisplay(userID, width, height);

} else {
regularvideodisplay(userID);

}
}

private void toggleFullScreen() {
if (isFullScreen) {
regularvideodisplay(null);
} else {
fullscreenvideodisplay(null, -1, -1);
}
isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;
}

public void fullscreenvideodisplay(@NonNull String userID, @NonNull int width, @NonNull int height) {
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) activeSpeakerContainer.getLayoutParams();
if(width <= 0 || height <=0) {
width = metrics.widthPixels;
height = metrics.heightPixels;
}
params.leftMargin = 0;
params.topMargin = 300;
activeSpeakerVideo.setEnabled(true);
activeSpeakerContainer.setRotation(90);
float scale ;
if(height > width ) {
scale = (height * 1.0f) / (width * 1.0f);
}else{
scale = (width * 1.0f) / (height * 1.0f);
}
activeSpeakerContainer.setScaleX(scale);
groupCallerList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

public void regularvideodisplay(@NonNull String userID) {
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) activeSpeakerContainer.getLayoutParams();

params.width =  metrics.widthPixels;
params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
params.leftMargin = 0;
params.topMargin = 0;
activeSpeakerVideo.setEnabled(false);
activeSpeakerContainer.setRotation(0);
activeSpeakerContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
groupCallerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
activeSpeakerContainer.setScaleX(1);
activeSpeakerContainer.setScaleY(1);
}

@Override
protected void refresh() {
// Refresh activeCaller's avatar
final Caller activeCaller = callHelper.getActiveCaller();
if (activeCaller != null) {
setActiveSpeakerAvator(activeCaller);
}

// Refresh other callers' avatars
callerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void setActiveSpeakerAvator(@NonNull final Caller activeCaller) {

if (activeCaller.getImage() != null) {

activeSpeakerImage.setImageBitmap(activeCaller.getImage());
} else {

activeSpeakerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.call_default_profile);
}
}

private void swapVideoView(@NonNull final Caller activeCaller) {

if ((activeCaller == null) || (activeCaller.getParticipant() == null)) {
return;
}

final Participant activeParticipant = activeCaller.getParticipant();

if (activeSpeakerVideo.getChildCount() != 0) {

activeSpeakerVideo.removeAllViews();
}

final VideoView videoView;
if (activeParticipant.isMe) {

videoView = activeParticipant.videoStreamer.videoView;
} else {

videoView = activeParticipant.videoPlayer.videoView;


}
if (videoView.getParent() != null) {
Timber.tag(NPLCallFSM.NPLDebugTAG);

ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) videoView.getParent();
parent.removeView(videoView);
}

activeSpeakerVideo.addView(videoView, videoLayoutParams);
activeSpeakerName.setText(activeCaller.getName());
activeSpeakerName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

setActiveSpeakerAvator(activeCaller);

activeSpeakerImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
activeSpeakerImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

showActiveSpeakerVideo(!activeCaller.isVideoPaused());
callerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void resetUI() {
groupCallerList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
callProgressText.setText(getString(R.string.call_status_connecting));
callProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
callButtonContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
callStatusContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
callButtonContainerUnavailable.setVisibility(View.GONE);

activeSpeakerName.setText(getString(R.string.empty_string));
activeSpeakerName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
activeSpeakerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.call_default_profile);
activeSpeakerImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
activeSpeakerVideo.removeAllViews();
activeSpeakerVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
callerAdapter = new GroupCallAdapter(callHelper.getCallers());
groupCallerList.setLayoutManager(manager);
groupCallerList.setAdapter(callerAdapter);
showControlButtons(false);
onDurationTick(0, "00:00:00");
}

private void showActiveSpeakerVideo(boolean showVideo) {
if (showVideo) {
activeSpeakerImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
activeSpeakerVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

if(isScreenShareEnabled && screenshareuserID.equals(participantuserID)) {
fullScreenImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
fullScreenImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// do something when the button is clicked

toggleFullScreen();
}
});
}
} else {
activeSpeakerImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
activeSpeakerVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

fullScreenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
regularvideodisplay(null);
}
}

@Override
protected void onCallUnavailable() {
if (callHelper.getConvo().isPrivateChat()) {
showActiveSpeakerVideo(false);
//            callHelper.getSelfCaller().setVideoPaused(true);
callStatusContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
callProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
callProgressText.setText(getString(R.string.call_status_unavailable));
callButtonContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
callButtonContainerUnavailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
callerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}

@OnClick(R.id.callButtonCancel)
public void onCallButtonCancelPressed() {
callHelper.onCancelButtonPressed(cancelButton);
}

@OnClick(R.id.callButtonRetry)
public void onCallButtonRetryPressed() {
callHelper.onRetryButtonPressed(retryButton);
}

}
```

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/activeSpeakerContainer"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/groupCallerList"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<ZoomLayout
android:id="@+id/activeSpeakerVideo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/activeSpeakerImage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="48dp"
android:src="@drawable/call_default_profile" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/beta_calling_watermark"
android:layout_width="130dp"
android:layout_height="28dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_beta_calling_watermark_blue" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/full_screen_image"
android:layout_width="28dp"
android:layout_height="28dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:src="@drawable/fullscreen_icon" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/activeSpeakerName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="#AA555555"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:lines="1"
android:textSize="16sp"
tools:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/callStatusContainer"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#AA555555"
android:padding="8dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/callNameText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:lines="1"
android:textSize="14sp"
tools:text="" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/callParticipantCountText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/callNameText"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/callNameText"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:lines="1"
android:paddingLeft="18dp"
android:paddingRight="18dp"
android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/callDurationText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_toEndOf="@id/callParticipantCountText"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/callButtonVideoRotate"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/callParticipantCountText"
android:layout_toStartOf="@id/callButtonVideoRotate"
android:lines="1"
android:textSize="14sp"
tools:text="03:16" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/callButtonVideoRotate"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/callDurationText"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:src="@drawable/ic_video_cam_switch" />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/groupCallerList"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:visibility="invisible"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/callButtonContainer"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activeSpeakerContainer">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/callProgressContainer"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/groupCallerList"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/groupCallerList"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/groupCallerList"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/groupCallerList">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/callProgressName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textSize="20sp"
tools:text="Caller Name" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/callProgressText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/callProgressName"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="@string/call_status_connecting"
android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<include
android:id="@+id/callButtonContainer"
layout="@layout/layout_call_button_bar_1_row"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/groupCallerList" />


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/callButtonContainerUnavailable"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/callButtonContainer"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/callButtonContainer"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/callButtonContainer"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/callButtonContainer"
tools:visibility="visible">

<Button
android:id="@+id/callButtonCancel"
style="@style/CallButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_call_end"
android:text="@string/dialog_button_cancel"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/callButtonRetry"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/callButtonRetry"
style="@style/CallButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_call_retry"
android:text="@string/button_try_again"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/callButtonCancel"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the adapter:

```
public class GroupCallAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupCallAdapter.CallerViewHolder> {

private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Caller> callers;

public GroupCallAdapter(@NonNull final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Caller> callers) {
this.callers = callers;
}

@Override
public CallerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
final View layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_caller, parent, false);
final CallerViewHolder viewHolder = new CallerViewHolder(layout);
return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CallerViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Caller caller = callers.get(position);
final Participant participant = caller.getParticipant();

if (caller.getName() != null) {
holder.callerName.setText(caller.getName());
}

if (caller.getImage() != null) {
holder.callerImage.setImageBitmap(caller.getImage());
} else {
holder.callerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.call_default_profile);
}
holder.callerImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
holder.callerImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

final VideoView videoView;
if (participant.isMe) {
videoView = participant.videoStreamer.videoView;

} else {
videoView = participant.videoPlayer.videoView;

}
if (holder.callerVideo.getChildCount() != 0) {
holder.callerVideo.removeAllViews();
}
if (videoView.getParent() != null) {
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) videoView.getParent();
parent.removeView(videoView);
}
holder.callerVideo.addView(videoView, CallerViewHolder.videoLayoutParams);

if (caller.isVideoPaused()) {
holder.callerVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
holder.callerImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
holder.callerVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.callerImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



}
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return callers.size();
}

public static final class CallerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

@BindView(R.id.callerVideo)
public ViewGroup callerVideo;
@BindView(R.id.callerImage)
public ImageView callerImage;
@BindView(R.id.callerName)
public TextView callerName;

protected static PinchandZoomLayout.LayoutParams videoLayoutParams = new PinchandZoomLayout.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

);

public CallerViewHolder(View itemView) {
super(itemView);
ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

}

}
}
```

here's another layout for calls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/callerContainer"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

<ZoomLayout
android:id="@+id/callerVideo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/callerImage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:src="@drawable/call_default_profile" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/callerName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#AA555555"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:lines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
tools:text=""
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code might be helpful to you :

```
 private void exitFullScreen() {
        isFullScreen = false;
        btnFullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_full_screen);
        rlBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerEnabled(true);
        ((MainModuleActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) videoView.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = 30;
        videoView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private void viewFullScreen() {
        isFullScreen = true;
        btnFullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_small_screen);
        rlBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((MainModuleActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerEnabled(false);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) videoView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = params.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = params.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```